# 404 page not found in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an app wherein I let admin customize URL of anchor tags. When I customizes the URL on heroku from the active admin, and I click on the newly edited anchor tag, I see a 404 URL not found error. This error occurs sometimes and sometimes it finds the URL and works fine. I am unable to reproduce this strange behavior on my local. Although once I change the URL from the admin side and if I run 'restart heroku', the error goes away. Also on inspecting the anchor tag I always get the new(edited) URL. I hope this question is clear enough. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run `heroku logs --tail` in a console and retry -- you should see error logs which show you what's happening. There's not enough to go off with your question the way it stands.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, change your database.yml and add this options:

> raise_not_found_error: false

For me, i'm using MongoDB and in mongoid.yml, i'm using this code.

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV["MONGODB_URI"] %> 
    options:
      connect_timeout: 15
 options:
   raise_not_found_error: false
```